# Combined bar plot and points with offset in points when X values are not numbers ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I'm trying to obtain a plot like the one shown in [Combined bar plot and points in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28819135/combined-bar-plot-and-points-in-ggplot2), with the points off to the side of the bars. One of the answers suggests to subtract an offset from the x values in `geom_point()`, and that works; but my problem comes when x values are not numbers since I can't subtract a number to them.

For example, this works:

```
df = data.frame(Xval = c(2, 4, 6), Yval = c(5, 6.1, 5.4))

ggplot() +
  geom_bar(df, mapping = aes(Xval, Yval), stat = "identity", width = 0.5, color = "black", fill = "#92DAB8") +
  geom_point(df, mapping = aes(Xval-.5, Yval))
```

[image: And generates this plot (with my desired position of the points)]

But this does not work:

```
df2 = data.frame(Xval = c("A", "B", "C"), Yval = c(5, 6.1, 5.4))

ggplot() +
  geom_bar(df2, mapping = aes(Xval, Yval), stat = "identity", width = 0.5, color = "black", fill = "#92DAB8") +
  geom_point(df2, mapping = aes(Xval-.5, Yval))
```

Is there any way to do the offset like in the first plot? Ideally, I would like to have a solution that works in both cases since I want to make a "plotter" function and you wouldn't know beforehand whether the values ​​of X are numbers, but any solution (even one that implies doing the trick in two different ways depending on the X values) will be helpful. Maybe there is a way to get the actual X values in the plot, but I searched for solutions following this idea and found nothing. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case one option would be to use `position_nudge` to shift the points:

```r
plot_fun <- function(.data, nudge_x = 0) {
  ggplot(.data) +
    geom_bar(aes(Xval, Yval), stat = "identity", width = 0.5, color = "black", fill = "#92DAB8") +
    geom_point(aes(Xval, Yval), position = position_nudge(x = nudge_x))
  
    
}

library(ggplot2)

df = data.frame(Xval = c(2, 4, 6), Yval = c(5, 6.1, 5.4))
df2 = data.frame(Xval = c("A", "B", "C"), Yval = c(5, 6.1, 5.4))

plot_fun(df, nudge_x = -.5)
```

[image]

```r
plot_fun(df2, nudge_x = -.5)
```

[image]